# Microsoft Edge did not get updated in the latest October 2017 round

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have two computers, both connected to the same Microsoft account.  All the settings in the two computers are the same.  A few days ago, both the computers got updated to the latest October 2017 version.  One of the computers got the very latest version of Microsoft Edge, but the other one did not.  The latest stable version is `41.16299.15.0`, while this one is still stuck with version `40.15063.674.0`.

Both the computers are set to download from the `Current Branch`.  Both of them claim to have the latest update in `KB4041676`.  Both have (almost) identical settings, and as mentioned, I log into both of them using the same Microsoft account.

Any idea why Edge would not have been updated in one of the computers, and how I can trouble-shoot the problem?

Comment: What is the OS version of each computer?

Comment: @music2myear For both the laptops, the OS version is `Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems`.  They both run `Windows 10 Pro`.

Comment: I would guess this is most likely explained by MS not pushing minor updates to all systems simultaneously. A small variance like this doesn't seem to me to indicate any actual problem

Comment: @music2myear - Easier explanation.  Edge 41 is part of the 1709 feature release, one PC received it, and the other has not received it.  Hence the reason one PC has Edge 40 instead which was 1703.  *1607 was Edge 38 by the way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why Edge would not have been updated in one of the computers,
> and how I can trouble-shoot the problem?

You need to install [KB4043961](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4043961) on both computers.

[October 17, 2017—KB4043961 (OS Build 16299.19)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4041676/windows-10-update-kb4041676)

> For both the laptops, the OS version is Windows 10 Version 1703 for
> x64-based Systems.

If you are set to receive updates on the Current Branch you should be running 1709 instead of 1703.

> The latest stable version is 41.16299.15.0, while this one is still
> stuck with version 40.15063.674.0.

Edge 41 only exists in 1709 based on my research.

> Microsoft Edge
>
> Edge 41

Source: [Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://changewindows.org/build/redstone3/16299/pc)

Edge 40 only exists in 1703 based on my research.

> Microsoft Edge
>
> Edge 40.15063

Source: [Windows 10 Creators Update](https://changewindows.org/build/redstone2/15063/pc#674)

Comment: Current Branch is still 1703 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). 1709 is "Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted). I'd guess they'll roll this out in stages and push 1709 to Current Branch in a month or so.

Comment: Current Branch is Semi-Annual: “The Semi-Annual Channel replaces the Current Branch (CB) and Current Branch for Business (CBB) concepts starting with Windows 10, version 1703, which released for broad deployment on July 27, 2017.“ which means the author will be getting 1709 or can force the upgrade.

Comment: With the 16xx go-round there was a month delay between the CB becoming the CBB. I'd anticipate similar for this too. They've removed the CBB stuff to consolidate and added this (Targeted) tag to allow for staggered deployments.

Comment: I think you might be right.  I am going to accept this answer.